# Executing command using Java in MAC

Tags: java, macos, terminal, runtime

Trying to execute a command using Java in MAC. But getting "No such file/directory".

Command: `ios_webkit_debug_proxy <udid>:27753 -d`

Able to execute the command in terminal, but not through Java.
I am using Java Runtime exec() method for executing the command.

Where am I going wrong?Is there any other class that I should be using.

Comment: Please supply more information so we can find the problem. For example post the code you are using with exec() and the error message you get.